# How to implement Reachability for iphone application

Tags: iphone, reachability

I am developing an iphone application which uses internet.So in order to handle the network connection errors i would like to use reachability,but from apple site api reference it states that build and runtime requires iOS4 but i am developing application for iphone 2g
which only supports upto iphone os 3.1.3.So any one could help me in implementing the reachabilty class.

Thanks in advance for all stackoverflow masters........

Comment: I believe devices that do not support iOS4 are being phased out, you should really look to develop for iOS4 now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [modified Reachability](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree/master/External/Reachability/) in [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which includes support for older iOS versions.